# Using aggregate with options allowDiskUse in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

**Problem:**

My memory is getting exceeded while using sort in MongoDB query and tells me to use `allowDiskUse:true` option in the query. But in rails mongoid, aggregate function is not passing any options.

**The error I am getting:**

```
Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in. (16819)
```

**My Code/Query:**

```
result = ModelName.collection.aggregate([
      {"$sort" => {
          "created_at" => 1
      }}
    ], {'allowDiskUse' => true})
```

**My Objective:**

To use `allowDiskUse` option in the mongoid query so that I can get the sorted data by created time but mongoid does not support it I guess, so I need some alternative. Any suggestions on what I should do ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you run out of memory you really should rethink your aggregation, add a `$match` and `$project` to reduce the amount of data early.

Comment: it can't be reduced,... I need all data

Comment: then use pagination.

Comment: hmm ok , will update you when I do it. It has to sort like 6-7 lakh records.

Comment: I can't use pagination, because I have to use sorted data for calculating stuff so it has to be sorted by created time first, I have to do it like this, current_day_data - prev_day_data for every day, so for this it has to be sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below. I wanted just specific field hence I added "$project" in query.

`MyModel.collection.aggregate([
  {"$sort" => {"created_at" => -1}},
  {"$project" => {"_id" => 1}}],
  {allow_disk_use: true}
)`